# How to setup a model as default value of a OneToOne field in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I added a new model to my existing design to handle the new requirements. To do the migrations, existing data requires default values to keep up with new model designs. How to assign an empty object as default value.

```py
 class NewModel(models.Model):
     somedata = models.IntegerField(default=0)

 class TheExistingModel(models.Model):
     data1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
     newfield = models.OneToOneField(NewModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default= "?" )
```

The new field is added to the existing model and it requires a default value so that existing data in the database are updated. Also when new **TheExistingModel** instance is created the respective **NewModel** has to created.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the existing objects unchanged, you can set the null=True

```
 newfield = models.OneToOneField(NewModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True )
```

and when the migration is successfully run, you can remove the **null** attribute which will make **newfield** not nullable and then run the migrations again. After that you will always have to assign a value to new **TheExistingModel** object